# Detect if user presses button on a Wacom tablet

Tags: cocoa, events, macos-carbon, tablet, wacom

I was wondering if it is possible in Cocoa/Carbon to detect whether a key combination (e. g. `Ctrl + Z`) comes from a Wacom button or the keyboard itself.

Thanks
best
xonic

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume a Wacom tablet's driver is faking keyboard events that are bound to specific buttons. If this is the case, I don't think you'll be able to distinguish them as -pointingDeviceID, -tabletID, and friends are only valid for mouse events (which a keyboard event - faked or real - is not).

Comment: Yes, you're right. The Wacom tablet fakes a keyboard event so it's really just that. But your answer implies that it's also not possible to distinguish keyEvents of a USB keyboard from those of the built-in keyboard on my macbook. I find that hard to believe, at least the system should know where a key stroke comes from, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the "Express Keys", Wacom provides custom events with the driver version 6.1+

From the [Wacom developer docs](http://www.wacomeng.com/mac/Developers%20Guide.htm#_Toc86811500):

> WacomTabletDriver version 6.1.0 provides a set of Apple Events that enable applications to take control of tablet controls. There are three types of tablet controls: `ExpressKeys`, `TouchStrip`, and `TouchRing`. Each control has one or more functions associated with it. Do not make assumption of the number of controls of a specific tablet or the number of functions associated with a control. Always use the APIs to query for the information.
>
> An application needs to do the following to override tablet controls:
>
> 1. Create a context for the tablet of interest.
> 2. Register with the distributed notification center to receive the overridden controls’ data from user actions.
> 3. Query for number of controls by control type (ExpressKeys, TouchStrip, > or TouchRing).
> 4. Query for number of functions of each control.
> 5. Enumerate the functions to find out which are available for override.
> 6. Set override flag for a control function that’s available.
> 7. Handle the control data notifications to implement functionality that the application desires for the control function.
> 8. **Must** destroy the context upon the application’s termination or when the application is done with it.
>
> To create an override context for a tablet, send to the Tablet Driver an Apple Event of class / type `{kAECoreSuite, kAECreateElement}` with the `keyAEObjectClass` Param of the Apple Event filled with a `DescType` of `cContext`, the `keyAEInsertHere` Param filled with an object specifier of the index of the tablet (`cWTDTablet`) and the `keyASPrepositionFor` Param filled with a DescType of `pContextTypeBlank`.
>
> To destroy a context, send to the Tablet Driver an Apple Event of class / Type {`kAECore`, `kAEDelete`} with the `keyDirect` Apple Event Parameter filled with an object specifier of the context’s (`cContext`) uniqueID (`formUniqueID`).

Most of this only makes sense in context of the documentation page where lots of C structs and helper functions are defined for both Carbon and Cocoa. (This particular part in the docs is pretty far down.)